# feof() and fread() producing errors

Tags: php, io

Ok so I found this off somewhere this website and I tried this but it is just spamming my console with a ton of errors, I don't get what I'm doing wrong

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$dirPath = "masked on purpose";
$songCode = $_REQUEST['c'];
$filePath = $dirPath . "/" . $songCode . ".mp3";
$bitrate = 128;
$strContext=stream_context_create(
     array(
         'http'=>array(
         'method'=>'GET',
         'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n"
         )
     )
 );


 header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
 header ("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 header ("Pragma: no-cache");
 header ("icy-br: " . $bitrate);

 $fpOrigin=fopen($filePath, 'rb', false, $strContext);
 while(!feof($fpOrigin)){
   $buffer=fread($fpOrigin, 4096);
   echo $buffer;
   flush();
 }
 fclose($fpOrigin);
 ?>
```

[image: Error log]

What I'm trying to do is to make an online radio stream that scans a folder, and loops all the .mp3 files in it

An edit here:
I've changed the script to look like this

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$dirPath = "...";
$bitrate = 128;
$strContext=stream_context_create(
     array(
         'http'=>array(
         'method'=>'GET',
         'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n"
         )
     )
 );


 header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
 header ("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 header ("Pragma: no-cache");
 header ("icy-br: " . $bitrate);
$list = scandir($dirPath);
foreach($list as $file)
{
    if($file== '.' or $file== '..')
        continue; // skip, not a file or a folder

    if(is_dir($file))
        continue; // skip, not a file

    echo $file . "<br>";
    // define the file path
    $filePath = $dirPath . '/' . $file;
    // read the file
    $fh = fopen($filePath, "r") or die("Could not open file.");
    if ($fh) {
        while (!feof($fh)) {
            $buffer = fgets($fh, 4096);
            echo $buffer;
            flush();
       }
       fclose($fh);
    }
}
?>
```

The code works fine but the problem is that I want the stream to continue even when no one is listening to it, it restarts each time someone tries to listen to it.

Comment: You aren't checking your call to `fopen` to make sure it didn't fail. Turn on error reporting to see all errors while testing. `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fopen` function will return a resource to the opened file or a `FALSE` boolean value if it fails. Looks like your file is failing to open. Check if the `$filePath` is correct and that `$songCode` has a value.

Here is a code to read all files in a folder:

```
// get a list of all files/folders in a path
$list = scandir($dirPath);

foreach($list as $file)
{
    if($file== '.' or $file== '..')
        continue; // skip, not a file or a folder

    if(is_dir($file))
        continue; // skip, not a file

    // define the file path
    $filePath = $dirPath . '/' . $file;

    // read the file
    $fh = fopen($filePath, "r") or die("Could not open file.");
    if ($fh) {
        while (!feof($fh)) {
            $buffer = fgets($fh, 4096);
            // Do something with the buffer here...
       }
       fclose($fh);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried debugging the code and it turns out it was trying to find a file named ".mp3". Since I'm a beginner in PHP, can you write me an example on how to read all files in a folder?

Comment: I'm no longer receiving the error but I want the stream to run independently and not restart each time someone visits it.

Comment: I think that would be a topic of a different question.